# How to have user input state abbreviation and reject or accept in matched with list of abbreviations?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, match

This seems like an easy enough question, but I'm having trouble accomplishing this. Other threads talk about matching and the RE module, but I cannot get this to work.

```
def get_lead_state():
    print ""
    lead_state = raw_input("    Enter the lead's two letter state abbreviation ")
    lead_state = lead_state.upper()
    if None == re.match("[AL,AK,AZ,AR,CA,CO,CT,DE,FL,GA,HI,ID,IL,IN,IA,KS,KY,LA,ME,MD,MA,MI,MN,MS,MO,MT,NE,NV,NH,NJ,NM,NY,NC,ND,OH,OK,OR,PA,RI,SC,SD,TN,TX,UT,VT,VA,WA,WV,WI,WY]", lead_state):
        print ""
        print " == msg ==> ERROR! abbreviation not recognized!"
        print " == msg ==> Try again"
        lead_state = get_lead_state()

    return lead_state
```

For some reason, this is allowing inputs such as ZZ or VTA through. I've also tried putting `^` before the list of abbreviations, and I've tried placing `*` and `$` at the end. I'm not really sure why I cannot get this working.

--
On a side note, if it finds a match, why doesn't `re.match` return `True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

r'[AL,AK]' means match **one character** that is A, L, comma, A, **or** K and so on.

Simply use a look-up list:

```
states = ["AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA", "HI",
          "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD", "MA", "MI",
          "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", "NC",
          "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT",
          "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY"]
if lead_state.upper().strip() not in states:
    print " == msg ==> ERROR! abbreviation not recognized!"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `set` like this

```
valid = {"AL","AK","AZ","AR","CA","CO","CT","DE","FL","GA","HI","ID","IL","IN","IA","KS","KY","LA","ME","MD","MA","MI","MN","MS","MO","MT","NE","NV","NH","NJ","NM","NY","NC","ND","OH","OK","OR","PA","RI","SC","SD","TN","TX","UT","VT","VA","WA","WV","WI","WY"}
if not lead_state.upper() in valid:
```